# excel vba: copy cell value from one workbook to another?

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am trying to copy the value from cell b from the active row on sheet '`SupplierTracking`' when the text 'send survey' is clicked in column `BA` and paste this in cell `A2` on my other workbook '`Supplier Survey`' on the '`Data`' sheet.

For some reason I am not getting any error, however nothing is being pasted into the cell `A2` on my other workbook.

could someone please show me where I am going wrong. thanks in advance

```
If Target.Column = Range("BA1").Column And Range("BA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Send Survey" Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1112 As Worksheet
Dim ws2221 As Worksheet
Set ws1112 = Sheets("SupplierTracking")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\{server address}\assets\Supplier Survey.xls")
Set ws2221 = wb.Sheets("Data")
ws2221.Range("A2").Value = ws1112.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
'Optional if you want to close the workbook afterwards
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
```

Comment: When the "text is clicked", pass the value of the cell you want to send to `Supplier Survey` workbook into a `variable`, then open the workbook and put the variable value into the required cell.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the answer to my question, I needed to save activeCell.Row as a string variable like so

```
If Target.Column = Range("BA1").Column And Range("BA" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Send Survey" Then

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1112 As Worksheet
Dim ws2221 As Worksheet
Dim s As String
Dim r As String
Set ws1112 = Sheets("SupplierTracking")
s = ws1112.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
r = ws1112.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\UKSH000-File06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\Supplier Survey.xls")
Set ws2221 = wb.Sheets("Data")

ws2221.Range("A2").Value = s
ws2221.Range("B2").Value = r
'Optional if you want to close the workbook afterwards
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End If
```